# BitBucket Hook option not visible

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server

The below link talks about bitbucket hooks option which can be configured at repository level.

https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/how-tos/hooks-merge-checks-guide/

I do not see this option in my bit bucket account under repository settings. Can anybody let me know where I can find this option.

[image]

Comment: Did you see the others repository settings (Repository permissions, Branch permissions, Audit log, Branching model, etc)?

Comment: No I don't see above mentioned fields. I also updated the post with a screenshot.

Comment: What is the Bitbucket version?

Comment: The version is "Cloud". (There's no Trello integration with Server.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking at Bitbucket Server documentation but attempting to use Bitbucket Cloud. Bitbucket Cloud does not currently support custom hooks.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I am using bitbucket cloud version. Just one question I want to run a executable whenever any commit is pushed just to check if correct coding guidelines are being followed to bitbucket and if that executable returns false push won't be allowed. Is there any way to achieve the same in bitbucket cloud.

Comment: You can have people add pre-commit hooks on their local copies, or you can have a testing mechanism such as Bitbucket Pipelines review the commits after they're pushed, but custom pre-receive hooks (like what you're describing) are not currently supported in Bitbucket Cloud.